# Not able to identify the web element under span class in selenium

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I want to locate 'New folder' web element.

```
<span class="mc-tertiary-icon-text"><div class="ue-effect-container uee-AppActionsView-SecondaryActionMenu-text-new-folder">New folder</div></span>
<div class="ue-effect-container uee-AppActionsView-SecondaryActionMenu-text-new-folder">New folder</div>
```

I have tried with span class also with css selector but not succeeded.

Comment: Please provide more details and your code

Comment: Please add more details/code about your problem and your own efforts this far to solve the problem so that people can help you better. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: <span class="mc-tertiary-icon-text"><div class="ue-effect-container uee-AppActionsView-SecondaryActionMenu-text-new-folder">New folder</div></span>
<div class="ue-effect-container uee-AppActionsView-SecondaryActionMenu-text-new-folder">New folder</div>